# IntelliJ IDEA freezing on source code completion

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 10.0 for Java development. A few days ago it started to reveal a strange behavior with auto-completion: pop-ups with completion options appears as usual, 
but IDEA completely freezes after choosing an option.

Cache cleaning doesn't help.

Has anyone else encountered this?

**Update:** Another symptom: IDEA freezes when trying to auto-implement method (e.g. `toString`)

Comment: Can you try performing thread dump of IDEA JVM when this occurs? jvisualvm or jstack should do the trick.

Comment: This sounds like something you might want to ask the Jetbrains support and not the SO community.

Comment: Normally @Vladimir's solution must solve your issue. If it doesn't, please make sure the correct exe is running: idea.exe and idea64.exe and make sure you run it as administrator.

Answer (score 6):

This is may be due to garbage collector working hard.

Try give your IDE more memory. You can do it in `idea.exe.vmoptions`(if you use windows). Increase `-xmx` property to at least 512 MB.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the same issue you describe, but I have experienced long (but not eternal) freezes, where after a minute or two it came back to respond. This happened whenever I pressed Ctrl+Alt+Space in the code completion popup, which caused IDEA to load all project and external libraries to browse for possible completion options.